# How to increase a specific value by 1

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of values

```
(1, 90, 1, 0);
(1, 29, 1, 0);
(1, 220, 1, 0);
(1, 218, 1, 0);
(1, 312, 1, 0);
(1, 13, 1, 0);
```

Using Notepad++ I want to create a copy of every one of these values and increase the first by one every time.
For example the file should be

```
(1, 90, 1, 0);
(1, 29, 1, 0);
(1, 220, 1, 0);
(1, 218, 1, 0);
(1, 312, 1, 0);
(1, 13, 1, 0);
(2, 90, 1, 0);
(2, 29, 1, 0);
(2, 220, 1, 0);
(2, 218, 1, 0);
(2, 312, 1, 0);
(2, 13, 1, 0);
(3, 90, 1, 0);
(3, 29, 1, 0);
(3, 220, 1, 0);
(3, 218, 1, 0);
(3, 312, 1, 0);
(3, 13, 1, 0);
```

And so on, around 13,000 times

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your question must be limited to one method only, so as your preference is for notepad++, I have removed all references to the other methods you listed. Additionally, this site does not provide a free coding service, so if you want assistance, you need to explain in your question body what you've done yourself in attempting this task, the methods you used, and what happened when you did so. You should include with that any programming code, error messages, and debugging information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Python you could try:

```py
filename = "yourFileName.txt"  # the file where you want to have the values
n = 13_000  # number of times each should be printed, you suggested 13,000
lists = [[1, 90, 1, 0],
         [1, 29, 1, 0],
         [1, 220, 1, 0],
         [1, 218, 1, 0],
         [1, 312, 1, 0],
         [1, 13, 1, 0]]

with open(filename, "w") as file:
    for _ in range(n)
        for l in lists:
            file.write("({});\n".format(', '.join(str(x) for x in l)))
            l[0] += 1
```

<s>Make sure the file already exists, or else you'll get an error.</s> (**Edit**: that is not true, files don't have to exist in append `"a"` or write `"w"` mode; thanks to @DarrylG)

Also, I am assuming you want the brackets around your values as well as the semicolon, so they are also included in the file.

So your file would look exactly like this:

```
(1, 90, 1, 0);
(1, 29, 1, 0);
(1, 220, 1, 0);
(1, 218, 1, 0);
(1, 312, 1, 0);
(1, 13, 1, 0);
(2, 90, 1, 0);
(2, 29, 1, 0);
(2, 220, 1, 0);
(2, 218, 1, 0);
(2, 312, 1, 0);
(2, 13, 1, 0);
(3, 90, 1, 0);
(3, 29, 1, 0);
(3, 220, 1, 0);
(3, 218, 1, 0);
(3, 312, 1, 0);
(3, 13, 1, 0);
...
```

Comment: 1) File does not have to exists to open in append mode, 2) Wouldn't it be better to open the file before the for loops (with just normal write mode) rather than constantly opening/closing in the for loop?  But, I thought the answer was good overall so upvoted.

Comment: @DarrylG You are absolutely right, I updated my answer now. Thank you.